# Auto scaling input fields height depending on container

Tags: html, css

Could someone give an example how to scale input fields depending on the container height?
For example, I'm increasing the screen size, my div container(width && height) increases depending on the screen size, but I can't manage it out to increase input fields height property depending on my div container. The width of input fields increases automatically. So literally, height value is always the same.

To stay simple and clear, the bigger the div container becomes, the value of height of input field increases depending on the full div container value. I have 3 input fields in the div container.

Is this even a possibility? Because on bigger screens, input fields height looks really small.
I know about media queries, but at this situation, they're not helping. I would need a lot of media queries depending on different sizes, like every 100px.

```
    <body>
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="div">
        <h2>Container1</h2>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="div">
        <h2>Container1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.div{
    padding: 2rem;
    flex: 50%;
    height: 50vh;
}

.div input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us an example ?

Comment: Sure, give me a second

Comment: I don't know how to add running html/css code. The whole point is to increase input fields height depending on div containers height. Because right now, input fields width size increases automatically, and the height is like "fixed". Height do not scale depending of div vh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this solve your problem ?

```css
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.div {
    padding: 2rem;
    flex: 50%;
    height: 70vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.div form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.div input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="div">
        <h2>Container1</h2>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="div">
        <h2>Container1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```